# Configuration of AC Voltage Source for Sawtooth Wave

Tags: wave, synthesizer, homework

I have a little problem with circuit configuration as you can see below. 
Every Voltage Source has configuration - 120V/10 kHz
And 1,3,5,7,9 - 0 Deg, 2,4,6,8,10 - 180 Deg

I need to change voltage on every source in such way that I will see Sawtooth Wave.

I tried several different ways, for example, I had changed all votage like 120,240,360,480,600,720,840,960,1080,1200

But it did not help me.

Can somebody give to me some advice or hint?

Thanks

[image: sawtooth wave circuit]
UPD1:

So as I understand the frequencies of sawtooth wave is depends of harmonic's number. 
I had changed frequencies: 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100kHz
and I got something strange on oscilloscope:

Looks like I made new mistake

UPD2:
Finally everything looks almost perfect. I divide voltage by number harmonic

[image]

Thanks everybody for the help!!!!

Comment: That's homework, isn't it?

Comment: Do you know what Fourier transforms are?

Comment: @owg60, yes. I had no problem with calculation etc. Just problem with circuit. Looks like everything is simple, but maybe I just tired

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes

Comment: OK, you know about Fourier transforms.  Do you think the problem may not have been stated correctly?  You understand you need harmonics of the fundamental frequency to make this wave. I don't Think you are going to get there with just 10kHz.

Comment: @owg60 thank you for your answer. you mean that I need to change frequency on every voltage source?

Comment: Correct, the Fourier transform for a sawtooth wave uses different frequencies, not just one.

Comment: You are on the right track, but your numbers are off. Find the (correct)  fourier transform for a sawtooth, and you should have it.

Comment: @ambitiose_sed_ineptum thank you for your answers. one more question - I just need to change frequencies or voltage also?

Comment: both the frequencies and voltage need changed. You'll find there is a relationship between the frequency and voltage. The sources you use should match exactly what the fourier transform has, both in terms of amplitude of the voltage (outside the trig function) and frequency adjustments (inside the trig function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your voltage sources have the same frequency (and I'm presuming that they are sine waves. If you want to create a triangle wave then you need voltage sources of different frequencies that are harmonically related: -

[image]

[image]

If you are considering using a real op-amp I wouldn't use 120V as your basic signal amplitude.

Comment: Hopefully you have given the poster enough of a hint, but would you agree there is a difference between triangle and sawtooth?

Comment: Unfortunately triangle and sawtooth is different waves. But thank you in any case for your time

Comment: but I'm sure you can find a second signal that, when multiplied with the triangle wave, gives you the sawtooth, @ckopnio?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I hope :) I will try in one hour and then I will make update if I got what I need. Thanks for hints